# In William Gibson's The Peripheral, is Flynne Fisher's first name an homage to Tron?

Tags: tron, william-gibson, the-peripheral

In *The Peripheral* by William Gibson, protagonist Flynne Fisher runs characters in virtual games and remotely operates drones and, eventually, the devices known as peripherals. It struck me at some point that her name could be an allusion to Kevin Flynn, the arcade-owning main character of *Tron* who gets dematerialized and turned into a program on the game grid.

A modest amount of Googling brought up tons of noise, since Gibson and *Tron* are so tied into the evolution of cyberpunk. Has Gibson ever addressed the issue?

Comment: While it might be interesting to get a confirmation from Gibson, this strikes me as in the *so obvious it hardly needs be asked* category.

Comment: Not obvious enough for me -- and Tron was the second movie I ever saw in cinema, so "Flynn" definitely has related connotations for me. At least for me the question was a nice hint.